# Connect opencv2 video feed to a widget made in Qt designer, using Pyqt4

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt4, video-capture

I'm quite new with python and am trying to get a live feed going in my very simple GUI consisting of a few buttons and a Graphicsview widget. I have the following code which i've tweaked and added stuff to it and it's somewhat similar to what is already out there.

I'm pretty sure I'm very close to getting this to work, although im unsure about this line:

```
 self.ui.graphicsView = self.bildeviser
```

If it serves the purpose I think it does. (showing the image in the graphicsview widget). Also I'm currently getting the following error:

QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1

To be honest, I think I have some reduntant stuff in my code as the class BildeViser really just makes a widget? Which I dont really need. Also, some of the def's are not being used yet, just testing purposes. I just want to connect my graphicsView widget (which was made in QT designer) to the videostream coming from opencv. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from MyFirstUi import Ui_MainWindow
import cv2

class ShowVideo(QtCore.QObject):

    videoSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QImage)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ShowVideo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.run_video = False
        self.kamera_port = 0
        self.kamera = cv2.VideoCapture(self.kamera_port)



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def StartVideo(self):
        print "Video started"
        self.run_video = True

        while self.run_video:
            ret, bilde = self.kamera.read()

            if ret:
                bytter_farge = cv2.cvtColor(bilde, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                #Lager QImage
                qt_bilde = QtGui.QImage(bytter_farge,
                                        bytter_farge.shape[0],
                                        bytter_farge.shape[1],
                                        bytter_farge.shape[2],
                                        QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)

                self.videoSignal.emit(qt_bilde)

    def toggleVideo(self):
        print "Kamera stoppet"
        self.run_video = not self.run_video

        print self.run_video

    def avsluttVideo(self):
        kamera = self.kamera
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        kamera.release()
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()


class BildeViser(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(BildeViser, self).__init__(parent)
        self.bilde = QtGui.QImage()

    def paintEvent(self, _):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.bilde)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QImage)
    def setImage(self, bilde):
        self.bilde = bilde
        self.paintEvent(self.bilde)

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.bildeviser = BildeViser()
        self.videoviser = ShowVideo()

        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.videoviser.StartVideo)
        self.videoviser.videoSignal.connect(self.bildeviser.setImage)
        self.ui.graphicsView = self.bildeviser


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit((app.exec_()))
```